# How do we define local maximum on a surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

As we know, given a function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we say a point $q\in\mathbb{R^2}$ is a critical point if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(q)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(q)=0.$ But how do we define a critical point on $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. I saw on a book of differential geometry saying that given a local chart $X:U\rightarrow S$, $p$ is defined as a critical point on $S$ if the differential $df_p$ is a zero map. Then he deduced that $p$ is a critical point if and only if  for $f\circ X:U\subset\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $(f\circ X)_u(q)=(f\circ X)_v(q)=0$, where $X(q)=p$ How he came to this conclusion ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to think about how the partial derivative operators associated to a chart are defined. Given a chart on the surface $X:U\to S$ centred at $p$, with associated coordinates $u,v$ we define for a smooth function defined on $X(U)$ the partial derivatives to be 
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\stackrel{\text{def.}}{=}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(f\circ X)$$
where this makes sense because $f\circ X$ is a smooth map from $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, it makes sense to take its partial derivatives. To define the partial derivative at a point $q\in X(U)$ we get
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\bigg|_q \stackrel{\text{def}.}{=}\frac{\partial (f\circ X)}{\partial u}\bigg|_{X^{-1}(q)=p}$$
The same applies for the partial with respect to $v$. So, the author is simply writing out the definition of what it means to have vanishing partial derivatives with respect to a chart.